# create a connector to open fire

Tags: java, xmpp, chat, openfire

I need to implement chat application between a mobile user and a desktop application 
but I wouldn't use  xmpp protocol between mobile and open fire, it's another technology more secure so I would like to develop a connector to open fire which is an intermediate between mobile and open fire server

please tell me if it 's possible to do this and if you have any suggestion tell me please.

Comment: wat technology are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create your own Connector to be able to relay between your server and an XMPP server. http://code.google.com/p/xmppjca/